# Convert a LINQ List into XML in Asp.net MVC architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, xml-serialization

I have a list in LINQtoSQL and it has various relation in tables and now i want to convert this list into XML.

I am using this code

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), IncludedTypes).Serialize(xmlWriter, this.Data);
```

where this.Data has the list data.

but it throws an error

> There was an error generating the XML document.

because our tables has related to each other and in our list it also maintains all tables relations

Now How to convert a list into a xml?

Comment: What do you mean by inner exception?

Comment: `Exception` object has a property called `InnerException` check its value.

Comment: Its Inner exception is : A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type abc.Core.Model.Channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type abc.Core.Model.Channel`
that means `Channel` object has a property refers to another object and that object has a property refers to `Channel` object.

for example

```
Class Parent
{
   public Child Child
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
}
Class Child
{
   public Parent Parent
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
}
```

When serializing `Parent.Child` it will serialize `Child.Parent` so it will serialize `Parent.Child` again etc.

to solve this problem check this [post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/02/LINQ-to-SQL-and-Serialization)

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav,

Based on the comments in your question re the inner exception:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of 
type abc.Core.Model.Channel
```

I would suggest that you decorate ANY parent objects with a `[ScriptIgnore]` or `[XmlIgnore]` attribute. This will prevent the circular references from being actioned as the xml gets saved. The issue is due to the fact that the parent object in turn refers again to the child object. this reference goes on to infinity (and beyond :)) and will never resolve without you indicating that you don not wish to serialize parent objects.